# Is EOutOfMemory exception recoverable?

Tags: delphi, exception, out-of-memory

Does it make sense to continue execution after catching `EOutOfMemory` exception or now heap or stack is corrupted with a high probability?

I don't mean the case of `EOutOfMemory` caused by previous memory corruption due to bugs like writing to a wild address, I mean correct code that calls `GetMem` and catches `EOutOfMemory`.

Comment: sometimes it is. I saw people trying to allocate 3GB memory buffer in Win32 apps :-)
So that depends upon what u really tried to do before getting the error. In some cases that is recoverable.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, there's no point attempting to continue from `EOutOfMemory`. In my experience, chances are exceedingly high that the heap will be corrupted and future errors can be expected. Usually, the safest course of action is to terminate the process.

Comment: I suspect it is not recoverable, but I am not sure. I don't know the internals of FastMM and maybe Windows memory management.

Comment: In our server we claim memory at initialization that is released on an EOutOfMemory so that exception and other logging has some room to maneuver before we kill the process.

Comment: @MarjanVenema That's risky too, at least if your other code is going to use the corrupted heap. Note that the Delphi RTL allocates the single `EOutOfMemory` instance at startup so that it doesn't need to do heap allocation in order to raise the exception.

Comment: Yes, it is risky, but with a server that may take from 2 minutes to 6 hours to load (depending on the model that we are loading), any "real" information on the error is better than none.

Comment: David. In such cases, could I use Halt(0) or is it better to call WinApi (TerminateProcess or ExitProcess) directly?

Comment: @MatheusFreitas `Halt(0)` calls unit finalization and you can expect that to fail. I say that you should call `ExitProcess`.

Comment: Are the same measures for `EOutOfResources`, correct?

Comment: @MatheusFreitas That derives from `EOutOfMemory`. From what I can tell, wherever it is raised, it's game over so, yes, I'd call `ExitProcess`.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for bother you in this old topic, but I believe it is better than asking another question, that could be marked as duplicated. I captured a situation that could exhaust all available memory in my application.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I agree that there's no point trying to recover. But it can be useful in specific circumstances. For example, allocating large amounts of memory that depend on user choices, and if it fails you can back out cleanly and let them retry with different settings. I do this for converting point clouds to 3D meshes, which includes some steps where the memory requirements aren't known in advance. It just takes careful coding of the steps you want to be recoverable, with an immediate and clean backout path. For example, some of my data structures are bitmaps or buffers with each line allocated separately to minimize issues with fragmented memory. The constructors have try... except handling and throw an EOutOfMemory exception, and the destructors free any of the lines that were already allocated. I can't guarantee it will always work, but it has worked well enough to be worth doing.